# Matlab close all doesn't close all

Tags: matlab

Take this little example:

```
h=waitbar(0,'a window')
close all
```

The command `close all` here **will not** close the waitbar.
To close it I must use `close all hidden`.

But why Matlab considers `h = waitbar` as an hidden handler?

Comment: because otherwise you can find it...

Comment: +1 to @thang for existentialist interpretation. Worth an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get(h, 'HandleVisibility')` tells you its handle visibility is `callback`, so it's hidden when accessed from anything other than an internal callback (by MATLAB of your GUI code). `close all` operates only on visible handles, so your `waitbar` won't close.

**EDIT:** Looks like you can mess with this system and `set(h, 'HandleVisibility', 'on')`. Now when you try `close all` the `waitbar` will disappear.